# How do I update my node.js version on a Heroku rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, heroku

I have a ruby on rails app running on Heroku that needs node.js for some background tasks. Everything works locally with v0.10.18, but there's some bug in v0.4.* that makes my tasks fail.

```
blakeley$ node -v
v0.10.18
heroku run bash
~ $ node -v
v0.4.7
```

How do I update the nodejs version on Heroku for a Rails app?

Comment: Have you tried using a custom buildpack, like [heroku-buildpack-multi](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi)?

Comment: I'm already using that buildpack, although I'm hesitant to add node.js because node already comes installed on heroku instances, albeit the wrong version.

Comment: Have you tried adding a package.json, which specifies a specific version of Node to your app's root? *WARNING - this _might_ irreparably break your app.

Comment: Yes. It broke my app. Heroku claimed to install a newer version of node (-----> Requested node range:  0.10.x
-----> Resolved node version: 0.10.29) but heroku run node -v still returns 0.4.7

Comment: Bummer. You could always break the Node portion of your app out into its own service.

Comment: It looks like the order of the buildpacks matters. Putting nodejs before ruby appears to fix the node -v issue (but for some reason I no longer have any dynos running and the database is down)